# Timeout connection when using Gremlin to connect to Azure cosmossDB emulator

Tags: java, groovy, graph, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm trying have a crack at using Gremlin/Java graph mode with cosmossDB emulator and got into trouble.

Emulator is all installed, and running and certificate is imported to my Java keystore (I can connect using document interface so I know that's working).

The emulator web console is presently showing collections and not graphs.

My simple code (in Groovy script) looks like this

```
Cluster cluster
Client client

try {
     def builder = Cluster.build()

        builder.addContactPoint("localhost")
        .port(8081)
        .protocol ("https")
        .keyPassword("C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==")
        .enableSsl(true)

        cluster = builder.create()
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace()


}


client = cluster.connect()

String[] gremlinQueries = [
        "g.V().drop()",
        "g.addV('person').property('id', 'thomas').property('firstName', 'Thomas').property('age', 44)",
        "g.addV('person').property('id', 'mary').property('firstName', 'Mary').property('lastName', 'Andersen').property('age', 39)",
        "g.addV('person').property('id', 'ben').property('firstName', 'Ben').property('lastName', 'Miller')",
        "g.addV('person').property('id', 'robin').property('firstName', 'Robin').property('lastName', 'Wakefield')",
        "g.V('thomas').addE('knows').to(g.V('mary'))",
        "g.V('thomas').addE('knows').to(g.V('ben'))",
        "g.V('ben').addE('knows').to(g.V('robin'))",
        "g.V('thomas').property('age', 44)",
        "g.V().count()",
        "g.V().hasLabel('person').has('age', gt(40))",
        "g.V().hasLabel('person').order().by('firstName', decr)",
        "g.V('thomas').outE('knows').inV().hasLabel('person')",
        "g.V('thomas').outE('knows').inV().hasLabel('person').outE('knows').inV().hasLabel('person')",
        "g.V('thomas').repeat(out()).until(has('id', 'robin')).path()",
        "g.V('thomas').outE('knows').where(inV().has('id', 'mary')).drop()",
        "g.E().count()",
        "g.V('thomas').drop()"

]

for (gremlin in gremlinQueries) {
    ResultSet results = client.submit(gremlin);

    CompletableFuture<List<Result>> completableFutureResults = results.all()
    List<Result> resultList = completableFutureResults.get()

    for (Result result : resultList) {
        println(result.toString())
    }

}
```

The builder creates and client connects when I watch in debugger, but when I try the client to submit I get following stacktrace.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59992', transport: 'socket'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59992', transport: 'socket'
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:214)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:198)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client$submit.call(Unknown Source)
    at playpen.TinkerPop-Example.run(TinkerPop-Example.groovy:64)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submitAsync(Client.java:310)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submitAsync(Client.java:242)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:212)
```

I have a couple of thoughts. I have a "familyDB" up from previous document DB prototype, but I can't figure what gremlin configure method in builder in user to express this.

Further if you wanted to create dbs name from scratch and equiv of creating a collection for the graph vertices etc.

Has anyone got a working graph config for the local cosmossDB emulator, and what have I done wrong/missed to cause this timeout. Attached is shot of debugger before I start issuing client commands

[image: image from the debugger before client.submit]

PS - tried configuring cluster as per sample in Azure graph zip from GitHub.

My config file looks like this

`hosts: [localhost] port: 8081 username: /dbs/familyDB/colls/FamilyCollection password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw== connectionPool: { enableSsl: true} serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}`

And the modified code to get a connection now reads

```
try {
    File config = new File("D:/Intellij - Azure/quickstart-java/graph/src/main/cosmossDB-config.yaml")
    assert config.exists()

    Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build(config)

     cluster = builder.create()
    println cluster.dump()
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    return
}
```

and I have dumped the runtime values from the cluster instance which returns the following

`prop: maxWaitForConnection, with value 3000 prop: nioPoolSize, with value 8 prop: keepAliveInterval, with value 1800000 prop: loadBalancingStrategy, with value class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.LoadBalancingStrategy$RoundRobin prop: resultIterationBatchSize, with value 64 prop: port, with value 8081 prop: serializers, with value [application/json] prop: maxInProcessPerConnection, with value 4 prop: maxWaitForSessionClose, with value 3000 prop: reconnectInterval, with value 1000 prop: workerPoolSize, with value 16 prop: minInProcessPerConnection, with value 1 prop: class, with value class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster prop: sslEnabled, with value true prop: maxContentLength, with value 65536 prop: serializer, with value org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0@119020fb prop: factory, with value org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster$Factory@3d9f6567 prop: closing, with value false prop: channelizer, with value org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$WebSocketChannelizer prop: closed, with value false`

however the TimeoutExcption still occurs.

I have downloaded the gremlin console and tried to `:remote connect` but when I run commands I get this, which warns about not responding in timely fashion.

```
`gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-cosmossDB.yaml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
gremlin>
gremlin> g.V()
No such property: g for class: groovysh_evaluate
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin> :remote list
==>*0 - Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8081]
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8081] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
gremlin> g.V()
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
gremlin> y
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
`
```

I am still stuck and can't get this to work - what can I try next?

Comment: if helps anyone to answer - tried to open cluster through a conf file instead where the file reads  `hosts: [localhost]
port: 8081
username: /dbs/familyDB/colls/FamilyCollection
password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use `gremlin console` to connect my `Azure Cosmos DB`, which worked well.

My configuration looks like:

```
hosts: [jaygong.graphs.azure.com]
port: 443
username: /dbs/testdb/colls/jay
password: ****************
connectionPool: {enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

Please note the `:>` that precedes the `g.V()`,it is important when using the Gremlin console, with Azure Cosmos DB which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-gremlin-console).

[image]

Then, I followed your configuration and tried to connect `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator`.

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8081
username: /dbs/familyDB/colls/FamilyCollection
password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: true}
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

After a lot of trying, I also met the issue which is same as you.

[image]

Finally, I found this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599065-azure-cosmos-db-graph-api/suggestions/19636633-support-gremlin-apis-on-cosmos-db-emulator) and it seems that the `Cosmos DB Emulator` currently does not support the Gremlin API.

Considering for the cost, I suggest you use `Apache tinkerpop server` instead of `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` to test your code locally during the development stage. After the test is finished, turn to Azure Cosmos DB.

In addition, `Azure Cosmos DB Emulator` supports `Graph API` which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction).

---

**Update answer**

> By using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you can use the Graph API to
>   develop and test locally without creating an Azure subscription or
>   incurring any costs. When you're satisfied with how your application
>   is working in the Emulator, you can switch to using an Azure Cosmos DB
>   account in the cloud.

This passage can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction).However,after my research for the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graph&type=), the Emulator supported Graph API mentioned here only refers to `.Net`,
not refers to [java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java) or [node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java).

So,it seems that the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator is deficient because it might not be up to date with the most recent changes with the Azure Cosmos DB service.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: maybe just the wording the link here `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction` says you can use tinkerpop/gremlin to talk to azure.. This line on the page `By using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you can use the Graph API to develop and test locally without creating an Azure subscription or incurring any costs` led me to understand 1 could.

Comment: it maybe that the Graph API is another microsoft thing and not tinkerpop/gremlin.  and therefore the eumulator hasnt caught up with the live azure service.  frustrating.

Comment: your config looks similar to the github project configured also for live.  so looks like i'm going top have to work with gremlin server (for PoC) and look to reconfigure for live - frustrating

Comment: I notice the emulator only shows documents and not graphis in the web client it launches, but another post id had to stackoverflow came back saying they thought it did.  however proof is in pudding.  If yours doesn't connect, and mine doesnt it suggests the emulator is presently deficient.  bother

Comment: @WILLIAMWOODMAN Hi,WILLIAM.Please see my update answer.

Comment: Jay, that appears to be the core of the problem them - the emulator only works for documents and not graph. annoying but there we go - i'm now having a play with gremlin server locally and make sure i can drive that via API - and then i guess i'd have to retrofit to live azure cosmossdb - it just means i have to create a full account then on azure and i wasnt ready to jump that far in one go - bother

Answer (score 0):

As others have determined, CosmosDB emulator does not support gremlin server emulation at this stage.

One option is to use `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs` .net SDK, which extends the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` to support gremlin queries. This is capable of connecting directly to the CosmosDB emulator and uses the same implementation that CosmosDB gremlin server uses for processing queries.

The nuget package for Graphs SDK is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graphs/0.2.4-preview).

Graph SDK tutorial/sample project is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet#clone-the-sample-application).

And info on connecting SDK to CosmosDB emulator is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#developing-with-the-emulator)

Obviously this is not ideal given your scenario, but it would be an option for validating gremlin queries locally.

Unfortunately, adding Gremlin server support to the emulator is a little bit of a ways out for us based on the current schedule.

Comment: thats a botther really - i'd need to shift into .Net rather than use groovy/java/spring which is my 'natural' dev framework.  I know MS aren't naturally into java per se, but permitting the emulator to work at socket/io level with tinkerpop api calls (where the client just happens to be groovy/java seems like a no brainer and and a nice link for azure cloud with java/spring based devs.  this opens up azure to java based dev teams harmonising .net or java equally.  In mean time i'll drop back tinkerpop server i guess for local dev experience with graph APIs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to this defect in the Apache Tinkerpop library where it cannot reconnect to hosts after losing connection to them.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2044